# Are all strong acids the same strength?

Tags: acid-base, ph, concentration

Since the six strong acids dissociate completely into their ions, and the reaction goes to completion, does this mean that acids such as $\ce{HI}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ have the same acidic strength?

I know that 0.10 M $\ce{HI_{(aq)}}$ and 0.10 M $\ce{HCl_{(aq)}}$ both contain 0.10 M $\ce{H3O+_{(aq)}}$, which leads me to believe they are equally strong acids. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something called the ["solvent leveling effect"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leveling_effect). In short, there's a lowest pKa in a particular solvent, based on the basicity of the conjugate base.

In water, you're limited by $\ce{OH-}$. So given the same concentration of $\ce{HI}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ in water, they will indeed have the same pH.

In other solvents, you may have a difference between acids, depending on the pKa.

Comment: I don't think there is a lowest pKa in a particular solvent.  This study http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1739994 quantifies the pKas of nitric and perchloric acid in water by NMR.  There is also the method of measuring HCl vapor pressure http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/1936/tf/tf9363200743 . Maybe there is a lowest pH or at least a lowest p[H+] just due to the fact that there are only so many H3O+ ions that can fit in a given volume.  No way p[H3O+] can be less than -log 55.

Answer (score 2):

No, not all strong acids are the same strength

There are more than just 6 strong acid.

The acid dissociation constant ($K_a$) quantifies the [strength of an acid](http://depts.washington.edu/eooptic/links/acidstrength.html).  pK is negative log base 10 of $K_a$.

Trifluoromethanesulfonic acid pk <-13

Perchloric acid pK = <-9

HI pK = -9.3

HBr pK = -9

HCl pK = -6

sulfuric acid pK = -3

chloric acid pK = -1

nitric acid pK = -1

Comment: This estimation for triflic acid isn't correct http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v78-385